# Trying to make URL-Matching RegEx faster for an IRC bot

Tags: javascript, regex, url, bots, irc

Hello fellow programmers, long time lurker here xD

So I was writing this IRC bot on Node.js, and one of the main functionalities is to automatically timeout users that post links without having permissions.

After much testing and researching I came up with this regex that would match almost any URLs, considering that users will often try to circumvent the bot to post links without permission.

```
/((?!\w+\.+\s\w+\b)\w+\W*(\.|dot|d0t)\W*(aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|net|org|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|edu|gov|mil|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)\b)/i
```

It takes into consideration users adding spaces between dots, replacing dots with "dot" or adding special characters between the dots, while ignoring matches when users type something like "word. It was good" (since it is a valid url extension).

This regex takes care of almost any cases of users trying to circumvent the url protection, while matching almost no false positives, however my concern is that it might be a bit slow.

Does anyone know of a better regex that has the same function that runs faster or maybe know how to make improvements for this one to run faster?

Regex explanation:

Full regex:

```
/((?!\w+\.+\s\w+\b)\w+\W*(\.|dot|d0t)\W*(aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|net|org|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|edu|gov|mil|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)\b)/i
```

Groups:
`(?!\w+\.+\s\w+)` - Negative lookahead - Checks if user typed a word (\w+) followed by a dot or multiple dots (.+) and a space (\s), if so, check if the next characters are a word (\w+). If this regex group matches, then most likely the user is ending a sentence with a full stop or ellipsis, followed by another sentence, and therefore the regex shouldnt match, even if the second sentence starts with a possible url extension such as "is" or "so", and therefore the negative lookahead should stop the url matching.

`\w+` - A word - this is the first part of the url considering a url such as google.com (this ignores the url protocol, if present, and the first part of the url, usually www, since our goal is just to detect urls, and not actually extract them for some other purpose).

`\W*(\.|dot|d0t)\W*` - Any number of non-alphanumerical characters followed by a dot (or ways to circumvent dot) followed by any number of non-alphanumerical characters - This prevents users from circumventing the filter by typing urls such as google(dot)com as well as spacing between the url words and the dots such as google . com.

`(aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|net|org|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|edu|gov|mil|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)` - Matches any possible url domain extension - Not much to say here, this prevents false positives from users that do weird punctuations such as "phrase . Next phrase"

`\b` - A boundary match (boundary character or end-of-string)

Edit: Ive made the obvious improvement from `(ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au...)` to `(a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|c[acdfghiklmnorsuvxyz]|d[dejkmoz]|e[ceghrstu]|f[ijkmor]|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|h[kmnrtu]|i[delmnoqrst]|j[emop]|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|m[acdeghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|n[acefgilopruz]|om|p[aefghklmnrstwy]|qa|r[eosuw]|s[abcdeghijklmnorstuvxyz]|t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz]|u[agksyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw])` does anyone know of any more improvements, or a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel.

Comment: Technical solutions to social problems will always fail.

Comment: What if I want to detect url from spam bots (that also try to circumvent the url detection) does it still classify as a "social problem"?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly faster:

```
domainExtTable = { aero: true, asia: true, biz: true, ... }; // init just once
results = text.match(/((?!\w+\.+\s\w+\b)\w+\W*(\.|dot|d0t)\W*(\w{2,4})\b)/i);
domainExt = results[4];
if (domainExt in domainExtTable) { ... } // this is a match
```

It is hard to say, depends on how good the regexp compiler is.

Removing the lookahead is likely to speed this much more.  Just to be sure, you want to NOT match "google. com"?